# How to insert API response array string into database

Tags: arrays, api, integration

I am trying to integrate the Bank Payment Gateway where data submission and processes is working very well but the success response as below received is not being inserted into database as it is a string in the form of an array.

```
BRN=837740&STC=000&RMK=success&TRN=5230896525&TET=2020/02/08 11:54:18 PM&PMD=CD&RID=253357&VER=1.0&CID=3636&TYP=Test&CRN=802406&CNY=INR&AMT=10000.00
```

Foe eg: in this code BRN is a parameter and 837740 is its returned value similarly STC is parameter and 000 is its returned value.

Now I want to set all these values in a php variables so to insert in the data, if no value is returned then null should be stored in db for eg;

```
BRN=837741&STC=111&RMK=failure&TRN=1172146589&TET=&PMD=AIB&RID=126036&VER=1.0&CID=3636&TYP=Test&CRN=740076&CNY=INR&AMT=10000.00
```

I tried below code which worked if all parameter has returned values if not then it is not working as delimiter sequence disturbed.

```
$chunks = preg_split('/(=|&)/', $qStr,-1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    //print_r($chunks);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($chunks);
    echo '</pre>';
/*
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";    

    $nweString = $chunks[0];
    for($i=1; $i<count($chunks); $i++) {
   // $nweString .= ':'.$chunks[$i];
    }
    echo $nweString;
    */


    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "BRN = " . $BRN = $chunks[1] . "<br>";
//  echo "BRN = " . $BRN = $chunks[2] . "<br>";
    echo "STC = " . $STC = $chunks[3] . "<br>";
//  echo "BRN = " . $BRN = $chunks[4] . "<br>";
    if ($chunks[5] == "success") {$txtclr1 = '09CB00';}
    echo "<font color='$txtclr1'>" ."RMK = " . $RMK = $chunks[5]."</font>". "<br>";

    //echo "RMK = " . $RMK = $chunks[5] . "<br>";
    //echo "BRN = " . $BRN = $chunks[6] . "<br>";
    echo "TRN = " . $TRN = $chunks[7] . "<br>";
    //echo "TET = " . $BRN = $chunks[8] . "<br>";
    echo "TET = " . $TET = $chunks[9] . "<br>";
    //echo "BRN = " . $BRN = $chunks[10] . "<br>";
    echo "PMD = " . $PMD = $chunks[11] . "<br>";
    //echo "BRN = " . $BRN = $chunks[12] . "<br>";
    echo "RID = " . $RID = $chunks[13] . "<br>";
    //echo "BRN = " . $BRN = $chunks[14] . "<br>";
    echo "VER = " . $VER = $chunks[15] . "<br>";
    //echo "BRN = " . $BRN = $chunks[16] . "<br>";
    echo "CID = " . $CID = $chunks[17] . "<br>";
    //echo "BRN = " . $BRN = $chunks[18] . "<br>";
    echo "TYP = " . $TYP = $chunks[19] . "<br>";
    //echo "BRN = " . $BRN = $chunks[20] . "<br>";
    echo "CRN = " . $CRN = $chunks[21] . "<br>";
    //echo "BRN = " . $BRN = $chunks[22] . "<br>";
    echo "CNY = " . $CNY = $chunks[23] . "<br>";
    //echo "BRN = " . $BRN = $chunks[24] . "<br>";
    echo "AMT = " . $AMT = $chunks[25] . "<br>";
```

Please help....

Comment: whats wrong with my question, no one replied ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer after juggling with array and explode function..

thnaks